# Unable to train custom object detection model with TFOD2

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, faster-rcnn

Following is the error when I try to train my model with TFOD.

I've been following Nicholas Renotte : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U&t=9559s. Followed the exact same steps, but could not fix the issue.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

````
      return tf.nn.convolution(
Node: 'model/conv1_conv/Conv2D'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNIMPLEMENTED:  DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node model/conv1_conv/Conv2D}}]]
     [[Loss/ToAbsoluteCoordinates/Assert/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_43/_23]]
  (1) UNIMPLEMENTED:  DNN library is not found.
     [[{{node model/conv1_conv/Conv2D}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference__dummy_computation_fn_19540]```
````